# Returning duplicates based on one value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've been working with SQL Server 2014 Express for the first time and I've encountered a problem.

Basically, what I've been asked to do (as part of an assignment in school) is to return values from a regular "customer-table", based entirely on the customer's stored location.

My query looks like this atm:

```
SELECT 
    City, 
    COUNT(Clients.ClientNo) AS AmountOfClients, 
    Orders.Pieces * products.Price TotalPrice
FROM 
    Clients
INNER JOIN 
    ClientOrder ON Clients.ClientNo = ClientOrder.ClientNo
INNER JOIN 
    Orders ON ClientOrder.OrderNo = Orders.OrderNo
INNER JOIN 
    products ON Orders.ProductNo = products.ProductNo
GROUP BY 
    City, ClientOrders.Pieces, products.Price
HAVING 
    COUNT(Clients.ClientNo) > 1
```

Now to explain it - I've been trying to find all customers where the contents of the "City" column re-occurs and return only those - along with the total amount of their orders (seen here as currency) based on the contents of three other tables (which is why the JOINs are there).
The latter part is working, but the wrong clients get returned and instead of returning the actual "ClientNo", only the amount of clients found get returned. I can't seem to find the right course of action here.

Ideally, the returned information/output would look somewhat like this:

```
City, ClientNo, TotalCost     -- for each client that lives in the same City as another
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: you've grouped on city/pieces/price, which means all other fields in the query result will be "collapsed". you can't get any client IDs from this query AND get a per-city count without fundamentally re-writing the query.

Comment: You should group by only with City.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only `City` in the group by clause and also use

`SUM(Orders.Pieces * products.Price) TotalPrice`

in the SELECT clause to get the total sum from each city order (Sum of Products).